# Generating multiple dlls from one project

Tags: c#, build, csproj, csc

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867113/visual-studio-one-project-with-several-dlls-as-output) article and works great, but there is one problem that I couldn't solve. My project references to another project just beside and some cs files are using some the members from that dll. When I try building it is complaining that it doesn't have reference to that dll. How can I add reference to Csc task? Could anyone help me on that?

Help appreciated!

Comment: This might help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593366/c-sharp-compiler-does-not-find-dlls-solution-compiled-in-vs2010?rq=1

Comment: @kristianp I am not calling the csc task from cmd. I am doing it from csproj.

Comment: Oh, right-click on the "References" item in the Solution Explorer and select "Add Reference".

Comment: @kristianp I added a reference to that library. Still getting the same error.